# Mailtrap not sending email using NodeJS Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, mailtrap

I have been trying to send email trough Mailtrap SMTP server but it does not send the email. I am using `Nodemailer` module in `NodeJS` application to send the email. The given SMTP information(Email Sending; not Email Testing) by Mailtrap is as below:

[image]

Following is the configuration set up as in the code:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'live.smtp.mailtrap.io',
        port: '587',
        secure: false,
        requireTLS: true,
        auth: {                  
            user: 'api',
            pass: '********cc8d'
        }
    })
```

```
const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email, 
        to: 'query.anwargroup@gmail.com', 
        subject: `Mssage from ${req.body.email}: ${req.body.subject}`,
        text: req.body.message
    }
```

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send('error');
        } else {
            res.send('success');
        }
    })
```

I could not find out the cause behind not sending the email. Ay solution or suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a domain registered to Mailtrap, try to put an email from you domain in "from" field of mailOptions(even thought you don't have that email) because in some cases i faced a domain validation of the email sender.

Answer (score 0):

The port is not a string, loose the quotation marks, then you can also interchange to know which works for you, 587 and 25 did'nt work for me, but 2525 did.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'live.smtp.mailtrap.io',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {                  
        user: 'api',
        pass: '********cc8d'
    }
})
```